# [C#]how to fill colors in cell of a matrix in winform?

Tags: c#, matrix, colors, cell, fill

guys
I have coded to fill 1 cell with 4 colors.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQJ3g.png)
How can I fill all the cells in the matrix when I click 1 of them ?
Quest1: how to make the matrix?
Quest2: how can I know when click the cell ?
Quest2: how to use the code I wrote to fill one cell ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

guys!
I have solved the problem.
Make a button Matrix with "for" circles,and use “for” circles make the button.Text too.
I wrote codes in the .cs file, not the design windows like earlier.
Thanks![enter image description here][1]

That s the picture.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSDfQ.jpg